# Error Installing Blueprints Locally

Tags: cloudify

I'm trying to install my first Blueprints following website: http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.2/getting-started-deploy-blueprint-locally.html, but when running the command:

```
D:\cloudify-manager\cloudify-nodecellar-example>cfy local init --blueprint-path aws-ec2-blueprint.yaml
```

I get the following error:

```
'ami-d05e75b8' is not of type 'object'; Path to error: inputs.image
```

My aws-ec2-blueprint.yaml:

```
...

inputs:

  image: ami-d05e75b8
  size: m4.large
  agent_user: ubuntu

node_templates:

...
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to deploy locally a blueprint that should be run on an AWS VM.
If you wish to run Nodecellar locally please try to run: https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-nodecellar-example/blob/master/local-blueprint.yaml

BR,
Jonathan